# How can i handle Jquery tab close in codebehind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i use jquery tabs.

```
    <%@ register src="~/UserControls/Order/Control/OrderProductLicense.ascx" tagname="OrderProductLicense"      tagprefix="uc1" %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                closable: true,
                cache: true,
                show: function() {
                    var selectedTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
                    $("#<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID %>").val(selectedTab);
                },
                selected: <%= hdnSelectedTab.Value %>
            });
        });
    </script>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="tabs">
                    <ul>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptTabs" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li><a href="#tabs-<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"ItemIndex","") %>">
                                    <%#Eval("Id") %></a></li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </ul>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptTabsSub" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div id="tabs-<%#                DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex", "") %>">
                                <uc1:OrderProductLicense ID="OrderProductLicense1" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedTab" runat="server" Value="0" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

My tabs has got close button. But i want to when a person close my tab after i want to delete some data in my session list with my selected tab text. Forexample.

```
    public void TabClosing(object sender, string tabText)
    {
        MySession.OrderProductIdList.RemoveAll(p => p.ItemText == tabText);
    }
```

how can write code like this ?

Best Regards

Comment: Try "close: function(ev,ui) {}". Not sure about it works.

Comment: You need to use ajax to pass data from your jQuery to your codebehind.  [Here's an example:](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95525/ASP-NET-and-jQuery-to-the-Max)

Comment: remove: function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/Usercontrols/Order/OrderProductLicense.aspx/HelloWorld",
                            data: "{''}",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: ajaxSucceeded,
                            error: ajaxFailed
                        });
                    },
i write this but i cant handle in my codebehind ?

Comment: Could you clarify `closable` option?

Comment: And also, how you rendering tabs on a page? Do you using some data-driven control like Repeater or ListView?

Comment: i use jqery inside the repeater.like this;
http://forums.asp.net/p/1693184/4474572.aspx/1?Re+how+to+interact+this+jquery+with+asp+net+codes+

i add closable option. but i cant take my web method. How can i fix this?

Comment: I update my question you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markup:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
           $("#tabs").tabs({
           });


           $("#tabs span.ui-icon-close").on("click", function () {
                var itemId = $(this).data().id;
                $(this).closest("li").remove();
                $("#tabs-" + itemId).remove();
                $("#tabs").tabs("refresh");

                $.ajax({
                     url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/WebForm1.aspx/DeleteRecord") %>',
                     type: "POST",
                     dataType: "json",
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     data: JSON.stringify({ id: itemId })
                });
           });
      });
 </script>

 <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
           <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptTabs">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <li><a href='<%# Eval("ID", "#tabs-{0}") %>'>
                          <%# Eval("Title") %></a> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" data-id='<%# Eval("ID") %>'>Remove Tab</span>
                     </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>
      </ul>
      <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptTabsSub">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <div id='<%# Eval("ID", "tabs-{0}") %>'>
                     <%# Eval("Content") %>
                </div>
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
 </div>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        var dataSource = (from id in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                            select new { ID = id, Title = id.ToString() + " Title", Content = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }).ToList();

        rptTabs.DataSource = dataSource;
        rptTabs.DataBind();

        rptTabsSub.DataSource = dataSource;
        rptTabsSub.DataBind();
    }
}

[WebMethod]
public static void DeleteRecord(int id)
{
    //delete record by id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set EnablePageMethods = true in scriptmanager

```
 <input type="button" id="btnClose" value="Close" onclick="DeleteEntryFromSession();"/>

//javascript
function DeleteEntryFromSession()
{
        PageMethods.DeleteSessionEntry(para1,function(result)
        {
            //Success
            //your closing code comes here


        } ,function(error){  //error});
}

//c#
[WebMetod]
public static string DeleteSessionEntry(string para1)
{
  try
  {
       // HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionName"]; //To Get session 
       //Delete Entry from Session
       return "true"
  }
  catch(Exception)
  {
       throw;
  }

}
```

Comment: thank for your answer. how can i use your code inside my code ? can u give me example for this. regards